# How to write double NSArray with NSString in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays

Good evening. 
I have a static array `double numbers[10]`. This array is for the button tags [0-9]. So if I push button 0, array writes it to `numbers[0]=0`then I push 2 and the second index = 1 `numbers[1] = 2` etc.

I need to output them into `UILabel` so that I could see what buttons I did push. But not just buttons, I need to see the sequence like 021123 etc. I don't know, maybe I should use `NSString`, or I can output them like in C just in a cycle. I searched for some info, but I have found only how to work with `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`.
Thank you.

Comment: Actually what do you want ? NSString of what? Your question is confusing

Comment: Output them like in C if you know how. Why not? Good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use NSString

```
NSInteger index = 0

-(IBAction) someFunction: (UIButton*) sender{
    NSInteger tag = sender.tag;
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", yourLabel.text, tag];
    yourLabel.text = text;
    numbers[index] = tag;
    index += 1; 
}
```

I didn't check, but should work. Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: it works great except the one thing. it shows the string with NULL like 01123, 05433, 012345. ofc I don't tap 0 button.

Comment: @user3226374 i didn't get you, could you explain where your problem?

Comment: soz, It was my fault, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure of what you are trying to achieve but,

You are using c array you should use a regular C loop (example)

```
NSString *string = @"";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    string = [string stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i", ((int)numbers[i])];
}
label.text = string;
```

Comment: Maybe you could use *string = [string stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i", ((int)numbers[i])];*

Comment: I think, you shouldn't use loop. Coz if button tapped 2 times, for example, text of label would be something like `"2200000000"`. I mean other elements of array is 0

Comment: To be honest I don't understand what he said about buttons. I just provide the clue to get him achieve what he is trying to do.

Comment: Well, I know how many numbers I have in my array, because when I tap buttons the [id sender] valuse gets to array[value], then I value++ so I can write the next tap into the second cell. So I will use (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
Thank's a lot guys,  I'll try it.

Comment: Why are you using `%i` to print a double? You're supposed to use `%f` instead...

Comment: @H2CO3 Because he may stock double but he seems to use them as int. But I suppose he know IEEE printf specifications..